# regex help for these expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to redact some text using c#. I need help with the regex expression to match this. Here is a sample of what I am trying to read. It's from an invoice.

```
Date 2016.03.09 ItemMaterial NumberDescriptionOrder qty.UnitUnit PriceTotalPrice00010A17NT1each29.3829.661-1ADAPTER0002c2022each14.141414-IB4 POINTINPUT00031-9iAV3each29.9929.99-9iAV3 desciption which is awesome00019540005-011each1,010.00 1,010.00Long description of part which is 27.89 MM by 78.22"Total price inbefore applicable taxes4000.00
```

that is hard to read so here is the summary:

```
date20.03.2016 ===> should select nothing
each29.7530.651222 ===> should select 29.7530.65
each20,0009.752000,30.851222 ===> should select 20,0009.752000,30.85
each2,020,0009.752000,30.851222 ===> should select 2,020,0009.752000,30.85
each2,020,0009.752000,30.851222 ===> should select 2,020,0009.752000,30.85
each219.00219.00JJJJ1222 ===> should select 219.00219.00
the term for each is 29 days. item is great.22 days to  be shipped ===> should select nothing
the warranty for each 29 days. item is great.22 days to  be shipped ===> should select nothing
```

I want to do a regex replace and turn these expressions into eachDELETEDDELETED. I have tried the following regex which have resulted in nothing so far.

```
@"each(.*?).(.*?).\d{1,2}");
@"each\d *,*\d.\d *,*\d *,*\d.\d{1,2}");
@"each\d,*\d,*\d.\d,*\d,*\d.\d{1,2}");
```

Comment: _"should select ..."_ - explain in English why those patterns should be matched, then writing the regex will be trivial.

Comment: They have the word each and two decimal points. After the second decimal I want only the next two digits. The comas are optional. These are suppose to be prices which are being redacted

Comment: Give an example for input that starts with `each` and it should select *nothing* ?  What are the rules other than the line starts with `each`?

Comment: The text is coming from an invoice

Comment: @JinJoe And? what does this mean to us?

Comment: nothing = no match; each20,0009.752000,30.851222=20,0009.752000,30.85 which is a match

Comment: if you look carefully 20,0009.752000,30.85 is actually 20,0009.75 and 2000,30.85 which are item prices that need to be redacted

Comment: `^each(.+\.\d{1,2})` worked for your dataset.

Comment: @ChrisCharley : That solution won't work for the actual dataset which, as shown in OP's first example, is concatenated.  The answer I posted below also works on concatenated data.

Comment: @Enteleform Right, I overlooked that actual dataset (first line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of regular expressions that match your examples like from the comments above

```
^each(.+\.\d{1,2})
```

works but also captures the "each",  if you don't want to capture that part you can use [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html%20) like so:

```
@"(?<=each)..."
```

However, when I ran that with the above example it still captured values from your last two sentences whereas

```
@"(?<=each)(((\d*[,|.]\d{1,2}))*)"
```

gave the output you required for each one of the examples in your question.

I hope that helps!